# Progress bar по обводке

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как реализовывать подобный progress bar?

Суть: чтобы border был динамичный по ширине, при этом нужно учитывать и бока, пробовал решать через before, но ничего толкового не получилось, мб у кого-то есть готовые решения?

Answer (score 3):

Немного наркомании:

```js
var left = document.querySelector('.left');
var charge = document.querySelector('.charge');
var range = document.querySelector('input');
var progress = document.querySelector('.progress');

range.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  progress.innerText = `${range.value}/100`;
  charge.style.width = `${range.value}%`;
  left.style.width = `${100 - range.value}%`;
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: #212121;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  position: relative;
  
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.xxx {
  height: 100%;
}

.charge {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #0277BD;
}

.left {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #616161;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  border-radius: 0.9rem;
  background-color: #212121;
  
  transform: scaleX(0.98) scaleY(0.86);
  
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range" min="0" max="100" value="30" step="1">

<div class="container">
  <div class="xxx charge"></div>
  <div class="xxx left"></div>
  <span class="progress">30/100</span>
</div>
```

Но вообще это делается с помощью svg.